# How to return a dictionary from a database?

Tags: database, python-3.x, loops, dictionary, sqlite

I have written functions to access a database.

The table called `Books` has:

```
- a `book_id` TEXT column, 
- a title TEXT column, and 
- an author TEXT column.
```

For the first one, `run_query` is a function that connects the database.

`get_book_cnt_per_author` is a function that returns a list of tuples in this form:

```
'author', number of books
```

I don't know how to use the `run_query` function through the loop. I always got `None` for what I wrote.

I don't know where my problem is. I only get one book for each author.

Please tell me what is the problem.

def get_books(db, book_cnt_list, book_cnt):
    """ (str, list of tuple, int) -> list of str

```
Precondition: the elements in book_cnt_list are sorted
in ascending order by author name. 

Return a list of all the book titles whose authors
each have book_cnt books in the database with name db
according to the book_cnt_list. The book titles should be in 
ascending order for each author, but not for the entire list. 
Follow ascending order across authors, that is, the order
authors appear in book_cnt_list that is already sorted by 
author name. 

>>> author_cnt_list = get_book_cnt_per_author("e7_database.db")
>>> books_list = get_books("e7_database.db", author_cnt_list, 10) 
>>> books_list[0]
'A Christmas Carol'
>>> books_list[9]
'The Life and Adventures of Nicholas Nickleby'
>>> books_list[10]
'Disgrace'
>>> books_list[-1]
'Youth'
""" 

# HINT: First figure out which authors have book_cnt books
# using the book_cnt_list.  Then, access the database db
# to retrieve the required information for those authors.

# Do not call any other of your E7 functions other than run_query.
list1 = []
for i in book_cnt_list:
    if i[1] == "book_cnt":
        list1.append(i[0])
for j in list1:
    return run_query(my_db, '''SELECT title FROM Books OREDER BY Books.title ASC WHERE Books.author = ? ''', (j))
```

def create_author_dict(db):
    """ (str) -> dict of {str: list of str}

```
Return a dictionary that maps each author to the books they have written
according to the information in the Books table of the database
with name db. 

>>> author_dict = create_author_dict('e7_database.db')
>>> author_dict['Isaac Asimov'].sort()
>>> author_dict['Isaac Asimov']
['Foundation', 'I Robot']
>>> author_dict['Maya Angelou']
['I Know Why the Caged Bird Sings']
"""  
con = sqlite3.connect(db)
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute('''SELECT author, title FROM Books WHERE Books.author = ?''')
new_list = cur.fetchall()
new_dict = {}
for i in new_list:
    key = i[0]
    value = i[1:]
    new_dict.update({key: list(value)})

con.commit()
cur.close()
con.close()

return new_dict
```

Comment: post the code for the two functions if possible.

Comment: I posted it in the answer. Please look at it and see what's my problems. thanks

Comment: you should the code to your question not to the answers section. I can't the error, but I would encourage you to print the value of the `value` variable to ensure that  you're getting more that one book per author from the db.

Answer (score 0):

try changing the:

```
new_dict.update({key: list(value)})
```

for a statement like:

```
new_dict[key] = new_dict.get(key, list()) + [value]
```